# Word to PDF conversion in Ruby/Rails?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, pdf-generation

Is there a gem or library to convert word document to pdf files in ruby on rails?

Comment: No. But you could use Adobe Distiller, PDFCreator, or even Office 2007's Save-as-PDF-or-XPS add-in.

Comment: Does the conversion need to happen at the server end? Is the server Windows? (i.e. could you install Word on it?). What version(s) of Word documents do you need to support?

Answer (score 0):

If you can call a web service from Ruby then give [this one](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/04/convert-office-files-to-pdf-format-from.html) a go.

Comment: This is a java solution, how is this relevant to a ruby app?

Comment: It is not a Java solution, it is a web service solution. So if you can invoke a web service from Ruby, or any kind of other language, then it should work.